# Asp.Net MVC Authorize Options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

Have an application were 99% of the actions will require user to be logged in.

The options I've come across are -

1-)Create a base controller inheritance chain and apply authorize attribute at that level. Something like: BaseController > AuthorizeController, BaseController > PublicController. (don't like this because of the inheritance chain)

2-)Create a custom authorize attribute and use a flag to bypass authorization. Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746998/override-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc). (my preference so far).

What are other options/best practice? What about using web.config like in asp.net webforms? Reference [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871).  Does that do the same as the authorize attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  tab to and the web config file to control this; you can specify the authorization settings and it does work in MVC too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

Authorize approach would work, or you could build a custom ControllerActionInvoker (each controller has a reference to this).  This class runs on every action invocation, which seems appropriate.

Comment: "Use the tab to" ? not sure what you mean.

Comment: I don't know what I mean by that either :-)  Anyway, the authorization element still applies and is a great way to handle this.  Other option I specified also works.