# How to do 'opt-out' authentication in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, authorization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override Authorize Attribute in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746998/override-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc)

In ASP.NET MVC, you add the [Authorize] attribute above action methods to specify that users must be authenticated (and in the specified role where appropriate) to use that method.

This is a bit like 'opt-in' authentication - I have to remember to decorate every method I want to protect, which is error-prone.

How might I specify that everything requires authentication apart from the controllers or actions that I whitelist?

Comment: @Chris Marisic: I disagree. The linked article covers how to create a new Authorize attribute where you can specify that you don't require authorization. It doesn't cover how to require authorization by default. Presumably I need a new controller type or something.

Comment: @David you follow that question and then apply it as a global filter. Then you only attribute it on actions you want to opt out. The action level (or controller level) attributes will override the global action.

Comment: Oh, global filter? This is the piece of the pie of MVC knowledge I'm missing... :)

Comment: Ah, okay thanks. Are global filters just MVC 3?

Comment: @David yes MVC3. Prior to that your options generally consist of base class or tag it on all controllers then use specific actions to opt out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the **basic** idea. You should play with this to get the desired results - especially when some actions inside controller need authorization, some - not. 
As you know, each and every part of asp.net mvc framework can be customized. So is filter providing mechanism of it. First, create the IFilterProvider implementation for providing authorization filters

```
 public class AuthorizeFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
    {
        public List<Type> AuthorizationExcludedControllerTypes = new List<Type>();

        #region IFilterProvider Members

        public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            if (!AuthorizationExcludedControllerTypes.Contains(controllerContext.Controller.GetType()))
            {
                yield return new Filter(new AuthorizeAttribute(), FilterScope.Controller, null);
//return filter only if it is not included into AuthorizationExcludedControllerTypes list.
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And register filter provider into Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ...

            AuthorizeFilterProvider authorizeFilterProvider = new AuthorizeFilterProvider();
            authorizeFilterProvider.AuthorizationExcludedControllerTypes.Add(typeof(HomeController));

            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(authorizeFilterProvider );

            ...

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, you can't, but see this answer for information about creating your own custom authorization attribute to do it: [Override Authorize Attribute in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746998/override-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc).