# When inherited, will the require https be included?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, https

Defined:

```
#if !DEBUG
        [RequireHttps]
#endif
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public class AdminAuthorizeController : Controller { }
```

Used:

```
public class GlobalCrudController : AdminAuthorizeController
```

Will this ensure that the `GlobalCrudController` will have the `[RequireHttps]` markup when not in DEBUG mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, has this [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx). Attributes are inherited in C# in this case. A conditional compilation statement like the one you have used is pretty simple. It will include the code if the statement is true, otherwise it will not.

Comment: The conditional will not affect the inheritance?

Comment: No, not at all as long it is truly in debug mode.

Comment: It will not affect the inheritance; if you're in debug mode, the attribute won't be inherited because it won't be there at all. It won't be on parent or child class.

Comment: @PaulPhillips - And if not in debug mode?

Comment: If it's not in debug mode, it will indeed [RequireHttps]

Comment: @TravisJ You should research what conditionals really do. Once you know them, the answer is obvious.

Comment: A conditional compile will only include that code in the binary if the condition is met.. pretty simple. I'll add that to my answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because this attrib is already applied to RequireHttpsAttribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited=true)]
```

Comment: The authorize attribute is already included without that markup. Wouldn't this just be re-iterating the default?

Comment: Right - that's on the RequireHttpsAttribute. Correcting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [RequireHttps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute.aspx) attribute has [inherited property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx) "true".

Your condition does not influence on the inheritance.

But you can write your own attribute to avoid this inheritance like in this example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/747208/775779

Comment: The issue is with the `#if` condition for `[RequireHttps]`. Will the conditional prevent the inclusion of the attribute when inherited? The authorize will be included with this scenario, but that is an interesting link.

Comment: @TravisJ yes, it was just a misprint - corrected the answer. #if condition does not influence on the inharitence. in Debug mode both your controllers wont have RequireHttps attribute, in non-Debug mode both will have.