# If user lands on protected page then how to redirect based on user role?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I'm using Asp.net Identity.

Currently have 7 types or roles in the system. A user can only have 1 role.
How can I set the redirect URL based on the user role if that user lands on a protected page that his role doesn't have privilege to?

For example a `Student` user of role `Student` goes to `Teacher.aspx`. He is not authorized so the default is that he is redirected to the login page. But I would much rather redirect him somewhere else depending on his role because he is already logged in.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  There are a lot of questions on here about access rights and redirects on certain pages.

Comment: well basically I'm just using a web.config within the folder of the pages I want to protect. There I specify which roles are allowed. That's the only authorization I've done now. In my App_Start / Startup.Auth.cs I have specified my login page. Now it's come up that a user might be authenticated but still not allowed to view pages for other roles. I can check on the page load of every page for the user role and redirect but I was wondering if there was a better way, something perhaps that just needs some setup already part of asp.net identity.

Answer (score 0):

User the [System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute.  You can use it like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles="AuthorizedRoleOne,AuthorizedRoleTwo")]
public ActionResult Index()
```

By default it will redirect unauthorized users to a login page.  If that isn't what you want [have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746998/override-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc) (you can inherit from the attribute and change the behavior).

Comment: is this possible with webforms too?