# Preventing AllowAnonymous

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a base controller which is globally marked as [Authorize]. Is there a way to prevent Controllers which inherit it from overriding the authorization requirement by simply adding the [AllowAnonymous] attribute?

Here is my exact scenario: I have three base controllers: one is for anonymous users, and two are for logged in users, both of which are globally decorated with [Authorize]. Each new controller that is created inherits from one of the base three, depending on which functionality is needed. One of the [Authorize] controllers contains "highly secure" functionality which absolutely should not be run by anonymous users. A developer inheriting from this "secure" base controller accidentally decorated some methods with [AllowAnonymous] which enabled anonymous users to potentially access the "secure" functionality in the base controller. It was caught in testing but I thought it would be a good idea to prevent that type of mistake, and I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do that. For now, I have taken all of the code inside of the secure base controller and wrapped it in blocks of:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // do stuff
}
else
{
    // redirect to login page, basically simulating what [Authorize] does
}
```

The above accomplishes what I want, however it kind of defeats the purpose of the global [Authorize] decoration in the first place. I'm envisioning something along the lines of:

```
[Authorize(AllowAnonymousOverride=false)] // this doesn't exist, but might be helpful
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this functionality?

Comment: you can always change base controller attribute to allow anonymous

Comment: @qamar - actually, I want to do the opposite of that. I don't ever want an anonymous user to be able to run code in the base controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override Authorize Attribute in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746998/override-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @ocanal - I must have phrased my question poorly, since you also interpreted it with the opposite of my intention. I have added an example of what I'm looking for and why.

Comment: @ocanal - The link you provided was how to override the authorize attribute. This question is different because I ask the opposite: how to prevent from overriding the authorize attribute. Erik's answer does seem to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to derive your own AuthorizeAttribute.  The default AuthorizeAttribute looks like:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
  public class AuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
  {
    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
      if (filterContext == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
      }

      if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext))
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.AuthorizeAttribute_CannotUseWithinChildActionCache);
      }

      // This is the Important part..
      bool flag = filterContext.ActionDescriptor
                   .IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
        || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor
            .IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);

      if (flag)
      {
        return;
      }

      if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
      {
        HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cache.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0L));
        cache.AddValidationCallback(
          new HttpCacheValidateHandler(this.CacheValidateHandler), null);
        return;
      }
      this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
  }
}
```

Derive your own:

```
  public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
  {
    public bool IsAllowAnonymousEnabled { get; set; }

    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
      if (filterContext == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
      }

      if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext))
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.AuthorizeAttribute_CannotUseWithinChildActionCache);
      }

      // This is the Important part..
      bool flag = IsAllowAnonymousEnabled
        && (filterContext.ActionDescriptor
             .IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
        || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor
            .IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true));

      if (flag)
      {
        return;
      }

      if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
      {
        HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cache.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0L));
        cache.AddValidationCallback(
          new HttpCacheValidateHandler(this.CacheValidateHandler), null);
        return;
      }
      this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute(IsAllowAnonymousEnabled = false)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    // This will still execute Authorization regardless of [AllowAnonymous]

    return View();
  }
}
```

You can't call `base.OnAuthorization()` because it will Allow `AllowAnonymous`.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Can you please check the logic though? I'm thinking it should be: bool flag = IsAllowAnonymousEnabled && (filterContext... || filterContext...)

Answer (score -1):

First, you seem to have a controller with some methods and then your approach is to inherit it so that the same methods are exposed. I wonder what's the point of having two or more controllers that expose the same data. Was is the mistake of that developer or rather it is a custom routine in your approach?

Then, you expect to have an attribute that prevents other attributes but this is clearly not possible in the language nor in the mvc framework.

Third, someone wrote a controller without unit tests or maybe with tests but no one verified these tests so that the issue was caught during manual testing phase. This indicates that the issue is wider and not only restricted to inheritance - suppose your developer wrote a controller that doesn't inherit anything and still exposes some critical data because of allow anonymous mark. Then what? Even if you have a remedy for your original issue, it wouldn't be able to catch the new possible issue.

My advice would be to have a custom analyzer attached to the post build event that scans all possible controllers and makes a list of all anonymous and restricted actions and compares it to a previously generated list. If there is a change, then an alert is created and someone has to resolve the issue manually, either by approving newly created actions or rejecting changes because a bug has been introduced.

Comment: To your points: 1: It wasn't exposing similar methods, rather the "secure" functionality in the base controller is done within "protected override void OnActionExecuting". 2: I believe this is where the failure was- assuming [Authorize] could guarantee security, which it cannot. 3: Unit tests could have been written to ensure authentication, likely also by using if (Request.IsAuthenticated).