# Is it possible to decorate a class or action to ignore a global attribute such as AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET4.5, C# and Razor.

I would like to set an attribute globably ie AuthorizeAttribute. However I need to ensure that some classes and/or actions ignore this global setting. Is it possible to decorate a class and/or action to ensure this, and if so how?

Many thanks.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746998/override-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc) may help

Comment: Yes this does look very interesting thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`[AllowAnonymous]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute (which is the default in ASP.NET MVC) to override your `[Authorize]` attribute

Assuming you have added your customized authorization logic to the default `FilterConfig` class:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new MyCustomAuthorizationAttribute());
    }
}
```

You can override that setting by decorating your controllers/action methods with `[AllowAnonymous]`:

```
// To allow anonymous access to all action methods
[AllowAnonymous]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // Only allow the Index action method to be called anonymously
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I meant this question to be about how to exclude attribute filters from controllers and actions. I was just using Authorize as an example. I have come across Filter Providers. Just reading up on it now. For Example I have anoter attribute here called "IsValidURLRequestAttribute" ie [IsValidURLRequest] which I want to apply globally and have something like [IsValidURLRequest(false)] on all classes or actions where it should not be used.

Comment: @SamJolly In that case, the cleanest way is to derive your controllers from an abstract controller and override the the `On<Filter>` Methods. You can read more on [Filtering in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(vs.98).aspx)