# How to allow anonymous visitor, but not allow logged in user on action method in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Please some one show any possibility to allow anonymous visitor but not allow logged in user on action method in c# mvc5.

In my case i have to not allow only some specific user as per their role

ex User in Admin role Not allowed

but

User in Worker role is allowed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force only anonymous access to controller action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513828/how-to-force-only-anonymous-access-to-controller-action)

Comment: Your shown answer is not correct in my case

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Allow anonymous users or users in a specific role?

Comment: Allow anonymous,Allow user logged in specific role(ex:Worker),but not allow user logged in specific role(ex:Admin)

Comment: The links provided by @Kamo actually do supply what you need. All you have to do is create the logic to allow only certain roles (e.g. Worker).

Comment: @Nirav - the idea provided in linked post is correct for your case. All you have to do is to implement your custom logic on your own.

Comment: Ok i am trying to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i get correct solution

```
public class AllowAnonymousOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            bool userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            if (userId)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") || HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Doctor"))
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");

                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to all that help me in my trouble