# Redirect users in an MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application what restricts the user from accessing controller actions based on a value stored in the session.

I have implemented as follows:

```
public partial class MyBookingController : CruisesDesktopControllerBase
{
    private bool CheckLoggedIn()
    {
        return MyBookingSessionInfo.OzBookingId > 0;
    }

    public virtual ActionResult Summary()
    {
        //Ensure user is logged in
        if (!CheckLoggedIn())
            return RedirectToAction(MVC.MyBooking.Login());

        //Prepare the view model
        SummaryViewModel summaryViewModel = new SummaryViewModel
                                            {
                                                OzBookingId = MyBookingSessionInfo.OzBookingId
                                            };

        return View(summaryViewModel);
    }

}
```

So instead of doing the if test at the top of controller actions I want to protect, is there a way to do this where the controller action could be annotated in some way to enforce the "logged in restriction" and hence removing the if test block?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override Authorize Attribute in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746998/override-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Yes, using the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke [Authorize] assumes use of the MS authentication pipeline which in this case I am not.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and override `AuthorizeCore` method.

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return /* custom logic */;          
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this attribute on your action.

```
[AuthorizeUser]
public virtual ActionResult Summary()
```

Comment: That does the authorization part of things. How do I control where the redirection happens when authorization fails?

Comment: That's your `/* custom logic */`

Comment: @BrendanGreen That returns a BOOLEAN. So lets say I return FALSE. How do I control where the redirection goes?

Comment: Override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` and do your redirection there

Comment: So don't return the bool and just redirect to action from there? I'll give it a go..... Does not feel clean then as the attribute needs to "know" stuff about the controller which seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the AuthorizeAttribute and then override the following methods `AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase)` - authorization logic 
`HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext)` - Logic when authorization fails

```
public class CheckLoggedInAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) 
    {
        //Authorization logic Here. You can access the session using httpContext. Return false if your authorization fails
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //Logic when authorization fails, modify the ViewResult or something.
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterConext)
    }
}
```